# Instance store backed EC2 instance cannot boot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-instance-store

Approximately 3 years ago my boss had another company setup our AWS services. This company used an instance-store backed AMI and unfortunately i cannot launch any new instances from it (the AMI) as it will not boot.

The problem appears to be that it cannot mount an EBS volume to /data, despite me attaching the device to the same block that it is on the running instance "/dev/sdg"

It looks like in the fstab they have not added a nobootwait for the /data drive, here is their entry in fstab:

```
    /dev/xvdg1 /data ext4 noatime 0 0
```

All i need to do is to be able to edit the AMI and tweak that line in fstab or alternatively send the "M" key to the server to skip loading that drive.

The primary server cannot be switched off, it is critical and i would be concerned if it does not boot we would be unable to copy it.

I need to duplicate this server and upgrade it then rsync the data over and swap it out, but i'm in a catch 22. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I would say you have to create another AMI from the running instance. This should help: http://serverfault.com/questions/446794/how-can-i-create-ami-from-instance-store-based-ec2-instance

Comment: You can always create a new AMI from current running instance, which possible include the monkeypatch.  In additional, you can use launch the AMI into a tiny instance, then fix it using EC2 login recovery process, test it and create a better AMI from there.

Comment: *The problem appears to be that it cannot mount an EBS volume to /data*  What specifically brings you to that conclusion?  Note also that `/dev/xvdg1` is not a volume, it is the first partition on a volume.

Comment: Hello @dsmsk80 i have been trying your link however i cannot seem to create the image. The ec2-bundle-vol process never completes. I have left it running in "screen" for 3 days now and it still did not complete. No errors are produced. Heres the output http://pastebin.com/jdGnGVLh I get a file in /mnt thats 10gig however no image manifest or parts.